# i want autocomplete in my dropdown with sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sonal_goyal/8MZkE/)

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="#">Delphi</a>

        <ul>
            <li class="menu">   <a class="menu" href="#">
            <div class="ui-widget">

              <li class="uili"><input id="tags" /></li>
            </div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

pls check the above code.
i want autocomplete in my dropdown menu .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add link to jquery and jquery UI

it is working fine after adding jquery and jquery-ui
check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8MZkE/1/)

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
<a href="#">Delphi</a>
<ul>

   <li class="menu">
<a class="menu" href="#">
    <div class="ui-widget">

      <li class="uili"><input id="tags" /></li>
    </div></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Forgot to load jQuery script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle needs a reference to jQuery but it's otherwise working.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help.